# Append values from dataframe column to list

Tags: python, pandas, list, append

I have a dataframe with several columns, and I want to append to an empty list the values of one column, so that the desired output would be the following:

```
empty_list = [value_1,value_2,value_3...]
```

I have tried the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['a','b','c','d'],
      'gdp':[1,2,3,4],
      'iso':['x','y','z','w']})
a_list = []

a_list.append(df['iso'])
a_list.append(df['iso'].values)
a_list.append(df['iso'].tolist())
```

Either way, I get a list with lists, numpy arrays or series inside it, and I would like to have directly the records.

Comment: So you need `a_list = df['iso'].tolist()` ?

Comment: If not, what is expceted output from you sample DataFrame?

Comment: if you append to a list, you get a list within a list. so, instead of appending, just get your list directly, problem solved.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could try this script if you need to append one column only:

```
a_list = df['iso'].tolist()
```

For extending a list by appending elements from the iterable, use [`extend`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711):

```
a_list = []
a_list.extend(df['iso'].tolist())
a_list.extend(df['country'].tolist())
print (a_list)
['x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Another solution is to use [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) with transpose:

```
a_list = df[['iso','country']].values.T.ravel().tolist()
print (a_list)
['x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 3):

`extend` does what you ask for . If you try do this with `append`, you can do something like:

```
import itertools
a_list = []
a_list.append(df.iso.tolist())
a_list.append(df.country.tolist())
a_list=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a_list))
print(a_list)
```

---

**Output**

```
['x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem arises from the fact that `df['iso'].tolist()` creates a list. The list is appended (given a place in the list at the single index), so you get a list of list. You can try:

```
a_list.extend(df['iso'].tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the data of each row of the Pandas dataframe we can use DataFrame.iat attribute and then we can append the data of each row to the end of the list.
In first for loop iterate over each row and create a list to store the data of the current row 
In second for loop iterate over all the columns and append the data of each column to the list  after that append the current row to the list

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['a','b','c','d'],'gdp':[1,2,3,4],'iso':['x','y','z','w']})
a_list = []
for i in range((df.shape[0])):
cur_row =[]
for j in range(df.shape[1]):
    cur_row.append(df.iat[i, j])            
a_list.append(cur_row)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the explanation to fullfill stackoverflows guidelines for good answers

Answer (score 0):

This example should be enough:

```
myList = df['iso'].tolist() 
print(myList)
```

Output:

> ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']

Comment: I need to append the results several times through a loop, so that won't work. Sorry for not specifying it in my question